# Is freemarker safe when allow user edit their template

Tags: freemarker

I'm new with freemarker, I need know about this problem too choose it or not, I will strip XSS by myself but I don't know are other features of freemarker safe when site allow user edit their template?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, goodness no! This is basically equivalent to allowing the user to evaluate arbitrary code. Removing XSS after the fact only removes one potential vulnerability. They'll still be able to do plenty of other things like manipulate POST parameters or perform page redirects.

Comment: Is it have any options to block some built-in var like Request ...?

Answer (score 0):

John is right. And letting the user actually edit freemarker templates themselves seems odd. If you are outputting user input again (like displaying the search term  on the results page) I'd suggest using the using the ?html string built-in, it'll save you from the most rudimentary xss attacks (e.g. "you searched for '${term?html}'").

Answer (score 0):

So as others said, it's not safe. However, if those users are employees at your company or something like that (i.e., if they are easily accountable for malevolent actions) then it's not entirely out of question. For more details see: http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_template_uploading_security